# Splitting characters after regexp_split_to_array

Tags: sql, postgresql, unnest

```
select name, (regexp_split_to_array(name, '')) from table
```

The result is `{a,b,c,d,e}`. Is it possible to split that up to individual rows and group by name so that it looks like:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on 9.4 or later you can use `with ordinality`:

```
SELECT name, u.*
FROM the_table
  cross join lateral unnest(regexp_split_to_array(name,'')) with ordinality as u(ch, nr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [unnest](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-array.html) function:

```
select name, unnest(regexp_split_to_array(name, '')) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`unnest()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html) with [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html) [**window function**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
WITH test_table(name) AS ( VALUES
  ('abcde')
)
SELECT *,row_number() OVER () AS row FROM (
  SELECT unnest(regexp_split_to_array(name,'')) AS name FROM test_table
) t;
```

Result:

```
 name | row 
------+-----
 a    |   1
 b    |   2
 c    |   3
 d    |   4
 e    |   5
(5 rows)
```

There is also great answer at SO:

- [**PostgreSQL unnest() with element number**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767450/3961156)